# Get metadata from TLS certificate from remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-server-side

I'm writing functionality for fetching TLS certificates from remote HTTPS hosts we run. We will then update a small database containing metadata from the certs, such as the expiry date ("not after"), thumbprint, and subject. These updates will be run periodically.

The project is Blazor server-side, so essentially an ASP.NET Core site on .NET Core 3.1.

[Demo code is on GitHub](https://github.com/Grubl3r/BlazorExamineTlsCertificate)

I've come up with one solution for how to catch and examine the TLS certificates - but I am not exactly thrilled at how it works. **I wonder if there is a more direct approach where I can read the certificates directly from HttpClient, without having to listen for an event as shown under?**

The only working solution I have been able to find so far is to use IHttpClientFactory and HttpClient, with a new instance of HttpClientHandler so that I can handle an event for validating the server certificate.

```c#
var certificateCatcher = new CertificateCatcher();

services
    .AddHttpClient("certificateCatcherClient")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(httpMessageHandler =>
        new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = certificateCatcher.Validate,
        });

services.AddSingleton(typeof(CertificateCatcher), certificateCatcher);
```

The TLS certificate gets passed to certificateCatcher.Validate above, which looks like this:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Event handler for HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback
/// </summary>
public bool Validate(HttpRequestMessage request, 
                     X509Certificate2 cert,        // here's the TLS certificate
                     X509Chain certChain, 
                     SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{ ... }
```

With dependecy injection set up this way I can just make a regular GET and the validation event will then receive the TLS certificate:

```c#
// Trigger code like this to get the TLS certificate
public async Task CatchCertficate()
{
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("certificateCatcherClient");
    await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Never mind instancing a new HttpClient each time. It's just demo code.

**All in all this seems like a roundabout way of getting hold of the TLS certificate (and certificate chain for that matter), so does anyone know of a different and more straightforward way of doing it?**

Also, the CertificateCatcher singleton thing isn't great, but it can be fixed by letting CertificateCatcher persist the certificate metadata, and then the consumers reading it back when they need it.

Comment: That is the only way HttpClient exposes it. If you are fine calling an external executable, there are other ways of course.

Comment: Alright. I understand spawning curl could yield the same information, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635253/display-received-cert-with-curl). Or perhaps by using a third party nuget package like [Chilkat](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/) which certainly can do [this kind of thing](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/http_getServerCert.asp). Maybe [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) as well. I am not familiar with either, and Chilkat has a price tag. Are there other good options?

Comment: Might rather want to do a HEAD as opposed to a GET.

Comment: I will do HEAD. That's a good point.